# Multiple thread server communication troubles in java

Tags: java, multithreading

So my problem is I want to create a system where threads can add information to an array in a different class, then wait while the data eventually get processed then returned to the thread that sent it. I've looked up how to set up BlockingQueues but I don't understand how to implement them for more then 2 threads and I don't think that's what I want. maybe. I want multiple threads to add the data to the class that's processing the information as it comes in, then when that data's ready to be sent back it gets returned to the thread that sent it. I've looked everywhere for the solution. The class that's processing doesn't know the specific thread until the data needs to be processed and sent back. Any solutions? This is the basic setup for the methods.

serverThreads.java

```
public void run{
    //Get the input from client and send it to processing class//
    process.add(input);
    //Wait for the input to be returned//
```

So this class is getting and passing the information to the class that's processing the data. Of course I don't know how to implement the code yet so basic comments will count as code for the server threads

process.java

```
public static void add(String[] data){
    //Add the user to the Queue to be processed
    Queue.add(data);
}

public void process(){
    //Hold the answer to the data//

    //Hold some data to be processed
    String[] data = Queue.get(0);

    //Remove the user from the Queue
    Queue.remove(0);

    if(Something being checked){
        //Set the response from the server
        answer = "true";//Needs to be returned to the thread that sent it
    }
    else{
        answer = "false";//Needs to be returned to the thread that sent it
    }
}
```

This class is supposed to process and send back the data to the thread that sent it. Because of how I want this class to work it needed to be separate and it's polling the string array list called Queue for data and when some is present it's processing it as fast as it can.

Maybe I'm doing it all wrong. If you can help at all that would be appreciated. I not new to java but I'm still pretty bad at it...

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [Thread pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).

what you need is a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

this simple example should explain it:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Test {

    public static final int THREADS = 5;
    public static final int TASKS = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        final Random random = new Random();
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);

        List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < TASKS; i++) {

            final int taskID = i;

            Future<UUID> submit = pool.submit(new Callable<UUID>() {
                @Override
                public UUID call() throws Exception {
                    String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();

                    System.out.println(name + " starting task " + taskID);
                    Thread.sleep(500 + random.nextInt(500));
                    System.out.println(name + " finished task " + taskID);
                    return UUID.randomUUID();
                }
            });
            tasks.add(new Task(submit, taskID));
        }
        pool.shutdown();

        while(tasks.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("tasks in queue:" + tasks.size());
            ListIterator<Task> it = tasks.listIterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Task task = it.next();
                UUID data;
                try {
                    data = task.future.get(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    System.out.println("task " + task.idx + " is done, data:" + data);
                    it.remove();
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    System.out.println("task " + task.idx + " not done yet");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Task {
        final Future<UUID> future;
        final int idx;

        public Task(Future<UUID> future, int idx) {
            this.future = future;
            this.idx = idx;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I took a look and that would be to hard to implement into the server. I opted to Just basically freeze the threads as they wait for the non threaded class. I can't believe that works out just fine for what I needed.